# Error al probar gema Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth2

Estoy intentando probar la gema Doorkeeper para implementar OAuth2 en mi API con Ruby On Rails.  Sigo los pasos aquí descritos:  https://doorkeeper.gitbook.io/guides/ruby-on-rails/getting-started

**Paso 1:**  `bundle add doorkeeper`

A mi Gemfile se le agrega esta línea:

```
gem "doorkeeper", "~> 5.2"
```

**Paso 2:**  `bundle exec rails generate doorkeeper:install`

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
/home/johan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Doorkeeper::Rails::Application (NameError)
        from /home/johan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
        from /home/johan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
        from /home/johan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `load_missing_constant'
        from /home/johan/Desarrollos/sample/config/application.rb:21:in `<module:Doorkeeper>'
        from /home/johan/Desarrollos/sample/config/application.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/johan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
        from /home/johan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
        from /home/johan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
        from /home/johan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
        from /home/johan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        from /home/johan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        from /home/johan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/johan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib64/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/johan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib64/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

He buscado en Internet y no logro saber por qué genera ese error.  Agradezco si alguien puedo ayudarme.

Versión de Ruby:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Versión de Rails: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recuerda que **siempre** es mejor que **copies y pegues** tu **código/error/texto** a que pongas un pantallazo del mismo. Así tal cual está tu pregunta, si alguien a futuro tiene tu mismo problema, no tiene forma de llegar aquí ya que con la imagen que subiste no hay forma que el texto del error específico que estás recibiendo se indexe en los buscadores.

Answer (score 0):

En tu archivo `config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb` agrega:

```
require 'doorkeeper/orm/active_record/application'

Doorkeeper::Application.class_eval do
  # your code here
end
```

Comment: Ese archivo ni siquiera alcanza a crearse;  sin embargo creo el archivo manualmente para probar tu respuesta y copio las sentencias que indicas.  Luego vuelvo a ejecutar "bundle exec rails generate doorkeeper:install" y me arroja el mismo error.

Comment: @JohanDonadoB. ¿y tu app se inicia después de haber agregado la gema en tu `Gemfile`? no sé si esté relacionado, pero ¿has probado a hacer `spring stop`? quizás eso ayude.

Comment: Es que antes de iniciar la aplicación debo terminar la instalación de Doorkeeper de acuerdo a los pasos que dice la documentación.  No sé qué es spring stop.

Comment: @JohanDonadoB. [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) es el precargador de rails para que cargue más rápido tu app. En general se ejecuta automáticamente en ambiente de desarrollo cuando inicias tu aplicación, sin embargo en algunas ocasiones deja precargado código de rails o librerías que pueden provocarte conflictos. Por lo tanto, para detener spring debes ejecutar lo que te puse en el comentario anterior, así recarga desde cero todo el ambiente de rails.